# How do I disable HTTP-level compression?

Tags: http, ssl

[BREACH](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39925/971), a new attack on SSL that targets HTTP compression, has recently been publicly announced.  The emerging advice for how to defend against BREACH seems to be: turn off HTTP compression.

So, how do I turn off HTTP compression?  What changes do I need to make to my Apache configuration?  Do I need to make any changes to browsers, too?

(While I'm here, are there any other resources suggesting what changes should be made on other web servers, like Microsoft IIS?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache compression is handled by  [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html). Just don't load or enable the module and Apache won't apply HTTP compression. Other compression (such as done within PHP) may be a bit more complicated, but BREACH deals specificly with `mod_deflate`-style compression.

There is also [mod_gzip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-gzip/), which is much less popular.

Comment: Don't just switch to gzip; you can be sure this attack will be adapted quickly enough.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The point wasn't *switch to* `mod_gzip`, but rather *also disable* `mod_gzip`.

Comment: Note that if you serve both secure and non-secure content (whether this is a good practice is a different discussion, but I digress), this will disable compression for *all* content, which may not be what you want.